# jquery,gridview,asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, client-side

I have a GridView in my .aspx page that is bind to a SQL server database table in code behind.
I also have one jQuery UI range slider. Now I have to filter data in the GridView based on slider's value and that should be done on the client side. In short, I have to build a page like in [following link](http://jiren.github.com/filter.js/filterjs.html), but don't know from where to start and how to do it. I googled a lot, but didn't get any complete guidance.

Answer (score 0):

An ASP.NET GridView control is fetching data only on server side. If you want to filter data on client side, you should first pass all the data to the client, and then conditionally display the appropriate rows based on filter's value.

ASP.NET has an algorithm to assign html ids to all it's controls when an .aspx-page is rendered. This algorithm is controlled by the [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) and [`ClientIDRowSuffix`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.clientidrowsuffix.aspx) properties. Once you know the client ids of all the rows, you can toggle their visibility with jQuery based on the current value of the filter.